# Spring RequestMapping params attribute IE 405

Tags: java, spring, internet-explorer, button, spring-mvc

I have a RequestMapping in Controller:

```
@Controller
class aController{
...

@RequestMapping("/action", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="actionName"){
//some logic
}
}
```

In JSP:

```
<form action="/action" type="POST">
 <input type="submit" name="actionName" value="actionName">
 <input type="submit" name="xyz" value="XYZ">
</form>
```

The problem is the request from JSP gets mapped when Chrome or Firefox browsers are used. But in IE it fails to latch on to the Request Mapping, because the way IE handles button names. To resolve this issue I have to add following:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="actionName" value="actionName"/>
```

The problem is there are several pages with multiple buttons mapped to different RequestMapping(params=""). I don't want to start adding hidden fields everywhere. Is there any better way to resolve this stupid IE issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the IE issue by using a hidden field with the required actionName of button passed as the value :

```
 <input type="hidden" name="actionName" value="actionName">
```

This solution solves the issue I face on IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you should use javascript to handle onclick events of your submit buttons and then from that function you can change the action of your form tag. Try adding the required parameters to the action and declare the form method as GET.

I think this should resolve your problem.

Cheers.

Comment: That will be a workaround which ignores the problem. In the solution you suggest, converting a POST to GET request is not always possible especially in form handling and at the same time to ignore Spring RequestMapping annotation with params attribute is not advisable. Also, as I mentioned in the question, the request maps to Controller when I use Firefox and Chrome. Its just the IE which causes the problem.